# Scrolling to an anchor

Tags: javascript

```
<a href="javascript:ScrollToElement('q1');">this question</a>.
```

I tested this code, why doesn't it work?
anchor q1 exists, but why won't it scroll to it?

Comment: Have you tried using `<a href="#q1">this question</a>`, does it work properly *without* the JavaScript? Have you defined the `ScrollToElement()` function? Are there any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Is this actually a native javascript function? I've never heard of it and can't find any reference for it. The upvote and comment is confusing me, they assume knowledge of how the function works.

Comment: Well then, janj, we'll need to see your code or at least a reference to the function's source code, and your HTML.

Comment: You could use this plugin if you're not against JQuery: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/02/smooth-vertical-or-horizontal-page-scrolling-with-jquery/

Comment: and ScrollToElement was a function from the Prototype framework which I did not have.  And it doesn't work even with the framework

Answer (score 3):

There's the native [`element.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollIntoView) function.

Perhaps that'll help, but you need to select the DOM element first.

If `q1` was an ID, it would go like this:

```
document.getElementById('q1').scrollIntoView(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code snippet scrolls to `name`'d anchor if present on the page.

```
var element = document.anchors.namedItem(name);
if (element)
    element.scrollIntoView(false);
```

[Live example of slightly enhanced anchor navigation](http://jsfiddle.net/G9M5S/1/). Note the drawback: `location.hash` no longer updated.

Other possibility:

```
location.hash = '#' + name;  // <- this simulates following the anchor link
```